# Case class mapping to csv

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
cat department 
dept_id,dept_name
1,acc
2,finance
3,sales
4,marketing
```

Why there is difference in output of show() when used in df.show() and rdd.toDF.show(). can someone please help?

```
scala> case class Department (dept_id: Int, dept_name: String)
defined class Department

scala> val dept = sc.textFile("/home/sam/Projects/department")

scala> val mappedDpt = dept.map(p => Department( p(0).toInt,p(1).toString))

scala> mappedDpt.toDF.show()
+-------+---------+
|dept_id|dept_name|
+-------+---------+
|     49|        ,|
|     50|        ,|
|     51|        ,|
|     52|        ,|
+-------+---------+


scala> 

  val dept_df = spark.read
  .format("csv")
  .option("header","true")
  .option("inferSchema","true")
  .option("mode","permissive")
  .load("/home/sam/Projects/department")

  scala> dept_df.show()
+-------+---------+
|dept_id|dept_name|
+-------+---------+
|      1|      acc|
|      2|  finance|
|      3|    sales|
|      4|marketing|
+-------+---------+


scala>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here

```
val mappedDpt = dept.map(p => Department( p(0).toInt,p(1).toString))
```

`p` here is a **String** not a **Row** *(as you may think)*. To be more precise here `p` is each line of the text file, you can confirm that reading the [scaladoc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext@textFile(path:String,minPartitions:Int):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]).

> "**returns** RDD of lines of the text file".

So, when you apply the `apply` method *(`(0)`)* you're accessing a character by position on the line.
That is why you end up with `"49, ','"` 49 from the `toInt` of the first char which returns the ascii value of the character and the `','` from the second character on the line.

## Edit

If you need to reproduce the `read` method you can do the following:

```
object Department {
  /** The Option here is to handle errors. */
  def fromRawArray(data: Array[String]): Option[Department] = data match {
    case Array(raw_dept_id, dept_name) => Some(Department(raw_dept_id.toInt, dept_name))
    case _ => None
  }
}

// We use flatMap instead of map, to unwrap the values from the Option, the Nones get removed.
val mappedDpt = dept.flatMap(line => Department.fromRawArray(line.split(",")))
```

However, I hope this is only for learning. On production code you should always use the `read` version. Since it will be more robust *(handling missing values, doing a better type cast, etc)*.
For example, the above code will throw an exception if the first value can't be casted to **Int**.

Comment: Thanks Luis for the explanation. what changes is required to make it work.I need the output to be the same as df.show()

Comment: @user2610 I updated the answer, hope that can help you.

Comment: Thanks @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez

Answer (score 0):

Always use spark.read.* variants since that gives you the dataframe and you can infer the schema as well.

Coming to your issue, in your RDD version, you have to filter the first line and then split the lines using comma separator, then you can map it to case class Department.

Once you map it to Department, note that you are creating a typed dataframe.. so it is a dataset. So you should use createDataset

The below code worked for me.

```
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object RDDSample {

  case class Department(dept_id: Int, dept_name: String)

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Spark_processing").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._

    val dept = spark.sparkContext.textFile("in/department.txt")
    val mappedDpt = dept.filter(line => !line.contains("dept_id")).map(p => {
      val y = p.split(","); Department(y(0).toInt, y(1).toString)
    })

    spark.createDataset(mappedDpt).show
  }
}
```

Results:

```
+-------+---------+
|dept_id|dept_name|
+-------+---------+
|      1|      acc|
|      2|  finance|
|      3|    sales|
|      4|marketing|
+-------+---------+
```